# Triggering AWS API Gateway functions with scheduled events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a set of function inside an AWS API Gateway.

I want to trigger specific functions at a scheduled time interval.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Functions of API Gateway are triggered only when a request made to API gateway. If you want the function to be executed on some scheduled, you can create a lambda function which will be invoked by scheduled events. You can get more details [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-scheduled-events) and [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Comment: @Chetan Thanks, you are correct.I have created the lambda function which will gets triggering now based on the scheduled events.Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an API Gateway that is invoking a Lambda function, the Lambda function can be triggered on a schedule by using Cloudwatch Events. Basically in Cloudwatch Events you create a rule to trigger your Lambda every x minutes. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

Comment: Bram: Thanks for your response. I got it.